# How do i perform feature selection for clustering?

Tags: correlation, dimensionality-reduction

I am new to Data science and trying to learn clustering? I have to partition the given dataset into different clusters into customer clusters based on their purchasing habits? How do I select the features that important for clustering?

[image]

Heirarchy_1, Herarchy_2 etc describe the product.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The data described in tables above is for purchases. You, however, want to segment users. Therefore, the first thing is to derive a dataset of user data.

As a first approach, I suggest that you create a table with one row per customer ID, where you have information about how many products the customer has purchased of each of the possible hierarchy values (e.g. customer ID: 312425, tableware products purchased: 5, cookware products purchased: 10, bath scale-manual products purchased: 0), and then do clustering on that.

Comment: Thank you @ncasas. This gives me a good start. Have a couple of questions. How do I arrive at what columns I have to consider? For example, the "region" might play important role in grouping of customers. Also, if i want to identify at a product level for example, people who are interested only in buying dinner sets, how do i arrive at that?

Comment: If the region is important, just select the region where each customer has bought more products.

Comment: About the "people who are interested only in buying dinner sets", you can't answer that by querying the data you have or by doing clustering. With data, you can know how many dinner sets a customer has bought, but not whether they are interested in buying. For that, you'd better set up a classification model.

Comment: Thank you ncasas. I will try and post my answer.